# Simple Vacuous Proof, Correct Approach?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am doing some practice exercises as I am starting out on proofs but I noticed that though I am getting the correct approach between vacuous and trivial proofs, I am not doing it in the same format as the solutions provided by the text. For instance, for a questoin such as 
$$ Let \: n \in N \text{ Prove that if } n + \frac{1}{n} < 2, \text{ then } n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} < 4$$

How I approached it was that I first define the statements $P(n): n + \frac{1}{n} < 2$ and $Q(n): n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} < 4$. Hence, it follows that $\forall n \in N, P(n) \implies Q(n)$. Since, $N$ is the set of all positive integers, I tried $n = 1$, in which case $P(1) = 2$. Hence, $P(n) = False \quad \forall n \in N$. As a result, I would conclude that since $P(n)$ is false $\forall n \in N$, it follows $\forall n \in N, P \implies Q$ is true vacuously.

Alternatively, the solution in the textbook takes an approach by starting: Since $n^2 - 2n + 1 = (n-1)^2 \geq 0$, it follows that $n^2 + 1 \geq 2n$ and so $n + \frac{1}{n} \geq 2$. Thus the statement is true vacuously.

Would my form of proof be correct here as opposed to the proof provided by the textbook ?

Thank you

Comment: The "Hence it follows $\dots$ sentence" is premature.  But you have indeed shown that $n+\frac{1}{n}\ge 2$ for all positive integers $n$. The book does it another way, one that works for all real $x\gt 0$, not just positive integers $x$.

Comment: There's also some weirdness when you act like $P(n)$ is a number: $P(1) = 2$, and $P(n) \ge 2$. But you've said $P(n)$ is a *statement*, and so should be only True or False, not a number.

Comment: I'd say a trivial proof was $n+\frac 1n <2\implies (n+\frac 1n)^2<2^2\implies n^2+2+\frac 1{n^2}<4\implies n^2+\frac 1{n^2}<2<4$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I made note of the fact $P(n)$ as a statement and will consider the different approaches.

Comment: It should be that $P(n)$ is false $\exists n\in \mathbb N$, after (only) knowing $P(1)=2$. Proving $P(n)$ is always false requires more than a counter example.

Comment: I understand what you mean with the $\exists$ but my question comes to the fact that is it not the case that for vacuous proofs, one is to show that $P \implies Q$ is true if $P$ is false for all cases ? If we write that $\exists \in N$ would that still be considered a vacuous proof ?

Comment: I think that it is trivial that $n+\frac{1}{n}\ge 2$ for $n\ge 2$, but perhaps that should have been said.